# How to fix" Permission denied when creating a hive orc table using spark "?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

First, I created a dataframe named 'ProDF'.
Then I needed to save proDf as a 'orc' format table.I used the code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
proDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("orc").saveAsTable("product_orc_table")
```

However, Spark shell  returned a failure:

> message:java.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>   user=junyanxu,access=WRITE,inode="/apps/hive/warehouse/product_orc_table":uma_kanagarajan:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

I tried change the permission of `/apps/hive/warehouse/product_orc_table` with the code:

```
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /apps/hive/warehouse/product_orc_table
```

But this code was denied and said:

> user=junyanxu is not the owner of inode=product_orc_table.

I expect I can create the orc table successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user and group ownership for /apps/hive is mentioned [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/10423/recommended-usergroup-ownership-for-appshivewareho.html)

to get going and execute your command do `hadoop fs -chmod 777 /apps/hive/warehouse/product_orc_table`

you need to be a hdfs user before executing following command

```
sudo su
su hdfs
```

Beware this is not a better practice, do follow required permission for hive in mentioned link.

Comment: Thanks! rbyndoor, the problem is fixed.

Comment: how is this resolved in a python script? Should sudo su. su hdfs be run in a terminal? What if I can only do this inside script?